# Getting Variable name in CMD from other variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I'm writing a short CMD script to use with CURL and encountered a problem I can't seem to solve with Google.

What I want is to get a variable depending on the names of the other variables for example:

```
    @echo off
    SET Example1 = Test1
    SET Example2 = Test2
    SET Example3 = Test3 (The variable data isn't this similar ofc)
    ...
    FOR %%G in (1,2,3) DO (
    ...
    *This is where I want to Echo out Something like Example%%G* 
    )
```

Just using

```
    Echo Example%%G
```

Doesn't work and I can't seem to find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET Example1=Test1
SET Example2=Test2
SET Example3=Test3
FOR %%G in (1,2,3) DO (
  echo. !Example%%G!
 )
```

As pointed out by Magoo, there should be no space between variable and value in SET command.

Answer (score 1):

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

Once you've fixed that, to output it, unless you use `delayedexpansion` (far too many SO examples...), try

```
FOR %%x IN (1,2,3) DO CALL ECHO %%example%%x%%
```

where `echo` could be `set "extra%%x=%%example%%x%%"`

beyond that, need more info on what you are actually doing...